# How to implement two buttons or more in an activity with one layout?

Tags: android, button, android-activity

I have one layout and more buttons, but I can't implement more buttons.
I can only implement one button within one activity to open another layout. How can I fix this problem?

Here is my code:

```
public class AppActivity extends Activity {
    Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        final Context context = this;

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, App2Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: use another button in xml and add listener to it just like you did for the first

Comment: You should have googled this first

Comment: Adding your XML would help pretty much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this-

```
public class AppActivity extends Activity {
    Button button1, button2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {
        final Context context = this;

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, App2Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, App3Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this:

```
button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, App2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);   

    }

});
button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        second Button code;   

    }

});
```

where button2 is the id of your second button defined in xml